# Is there a significance to the number of threads being used? Can I run out?

Tags: macos

Google Chrome currently has 49, which sounds like a lot, what's the limit? Will it slow my mac down?

Comment: Someone down-voted this, but I disagree.  Even as a "power user", I find the # of threads in use disconcerting, and also wonder what it does to performance.  I think it's a fine question, and people who know legit reasons why this occurs should add Comments or Answers, don't just down-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely assume that the folks who designed and implemented Google Chrome knew what they were doing. If they used 49 threads, it's because that's what they felt was best. If that was too many or close to the limit, somebody else would either make a new browser that used fewer or change Google Chrome to use fewer and the we'd all be using the improved version.

Comment: From the question, I don't get that the limit is 49, it sounds like that is how many the OP is using.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Yes. That's right.